# Push zero if value doesnt exists in array of objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I have array of objects. Please go through below code.I have three values 'A','B','C'.For example if B value doesnt exists in Mumbai I want to push 0.

[Plunker](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/D23yaKiulSMrZKgrJ40O)

```js
// Code goes here

var c = angular.module('myApp', ['angular.filter'])
c.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.finalArray = [];

    $scope.data = [{
        "id": "1",
        "place": "Mumbai",
        "name": "A",
        "value": "10"
    }, {
        "id": "4",
        "place": "Mumbai",
        "name": "B",
        "value": "20"
    }, {
        "id": "4",
        "place": "Delhi",
        "name": "B",
        "value": "77"
    }, {
        "id": "5",
        "place": "Delhi",
        "name": "C",
        "value": "11"
    }, {
        "id": "6",
        "place": "Banglore",
        "name": "A",
        "value": "14"
    }, {
        "id": "7",
        "place": "Banglore",
        "name": "C",
        "value": "100"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "place": "Delhi",
        "name": "A",
        "value": "30"
    },]

    $scope.finalArray = [];
    $scope.stationName = [];
    $scope.name = $filter('groupBy')($scope.data, 'name');
    angular.forEach($scope.name, function(k, v) {
        $scope.title = [];
        $scope.count = [];
        console.log(k, v);
        $scope.title.push(v)
        angular.forEach(k, function(key, value) {
            $scope.count.push(key.value)
        })
        var obj = { name: $scope.title[0], data: $scope.count }
        $scope.finalArray.push(obj);
       });
    console.log($scope.finalArray)
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.7.0" data-semver="1.7.0" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.17/angular-filter.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    
     {{finalArray | json}}
  </body>

</html>
```

Right now I'm getting output as 
`[ { "name": "A", "data": [ "10", "30", "14" ] }, { "name": "B", "data": [ "20", "77" ] }, { "name": "C", "data": [ "11", "100" ] } ]
But my desired output is [{name :"A",data :[10 30 14]},{name : "B",data : [20,77,10]},{name : "C",data : [0,11,100]}]`

Comment: Your expectation probably is wrong. It dont seem to match logically. Please revisit and update your expected result.

Comment: sorry i have edited my expected response please check once and help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have defined a function distinct which takes an array and returns the distinct values in the array. I then use this function get a distinct list of the names and places. I then map the list of names into an array of objects and for each name I map the list of places into the value for that place.

```js
// Code goes here

var c = angular.module('myApp', ['angular.filter'])
c.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.finalArray = [];

    $scope.data = [{
        "id": "1",
        "place": "Mumbai",
        "name": "A",
        "value": "10"
    }, {
        "id": "4",
        "place": "Mumbai",
        "name": "B",
        "value": "20"
    }, {
        "id": "4",
        "place": "Delhi",
        "name": "B",
        "value": "77"
    }, {
        "id": "5",
        "place": "Delhi",
        "name": "C",
        "value": "11"
    }, {
        "id": "6",
        "place": "Banglore",
        "name": "A",
        "value": "14"
    }, {
        "id": "7",
        "place": "Banglore",
        "name": "C",
        "value": "100"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "place": "Delhi",
        "name": "A",
        "value": "30"
    },]
    
    const distinct = (array) => array ? array.reduce((arr, item) => (arr.find(i => i === item) ? [...arr] : [...arr, item]), []) : array;
  
    const names = distinct($scope.data.map(obj => obj.name));
    const places = distinct($scope.data.map(obj => obj.place));

    $scope.finalArray = names.map(name => {
      return {
        name: name,
        data: places.map(place => {
          const obj = $scope.data.find(o => o.place === place && o.name === name);
          return obj ? obj.value : 0;
        })
      };
    });
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.7.0" data-semver="1.7.0" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.17/angular-filter.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    
     {{finalArray | json}}
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, I left a TypeScript type definition in there. Been a long time since I coded vanilla JS.